# Batch File is deleting files where it is stored

Tags: batch-file

I have created below Batch File for deleting java cache, IE history, temp folders but it is also deleting the files where it is stored.

Can anyone help me to know the error in the batch file?

Code

```
cd C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache
del /Q *.*

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

cd C:\Users\SHIKHA~1.YAD\AppData\Local\Temp
del /Q *.*

cd C:\Windows\Prefetch
del /Q *.*

cd C:\Windows\Temp
del /Q *.*

cd C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files
del /Q *.*
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `cd` approach is that if the current active directory is not in the same drive that the target folder, as `cd` does not change the drive, the `del` command is executed in the wrong drive.

Also, if the target folder does not exist, the `cd` will fail to change the active directory, but the execution continues and the code will delete a wrong set of files.

You can use `cd /d "c:\...."` to ensure you change the current active directory AND the drive, but it is still possible that the operation fails. You can use the conditional execution operator `&&`.

```
cd /d "x:\somewhere" && del /q *
```

This means: first change the current active directory and if the command has been sucesfull then execute the delete command.

But, it is easier to directly indicate what you want to delete

```
del /q "C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\*"

RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

del /q "C:\Users\SHIKHA~1.YAD\AppData\Local\Temp\*"
del /q "C:\Windows\Prefetch\*"
del /q "C:\Windows\Temp\*"
del /q "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\*"
```

Comment: @user5035889 in this case you must accept it as answer ! take a look at this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/tour